# Get data back from MySql database and display it on "UITextview"

Tags: php, mysql, ios, iphone, xcode

i'm trying now for a two weeks to fix an issue with my code and just got crazy already trying to fix it so here i'm here. I have a registration controller where I succsufully sucseded to upload users data into a database with their "macaddress" info to.Now I heard apple changed macaddress and it whont be avilable any more but this is my code and its working for me for now so if you can recomend on something else its will be good to.My main issue "here" is that i'm not able to display my users data back I need the data to be back to the IPhone by each particular user then I use "macadress" to get users Device ID but can't get it back into a "UITextView" how can I do that? what methods to use to display it the right way? Should I keep using "macaddress" or is there a batter way to get save users in a database? this is my code:

.m File

```
#import "MacAddress.h"
```

## ----- ##

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *user_description;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *user_website;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *user_email;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *user_subject;
```

## ------- ##

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:GET];
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];


NSDictionary *dic = nil;

if (!data)
{
    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Data not found !!." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    return;
}

  NSLog(@"data %@",data);

dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];

[_user_email removeAllObjects];
[_user_description removeAllObjects];
[_user_subject removeAllObjects];
[_user_website removeAllObjects];



 NSLog(@"Dictionary data %@",dic);



for (NSDictionary *obj in [dic objectForKey:@"r"]) {

    [_user_description addObject:[obj valueForKey:@"Description"]];
    [_user_website addObject:[obj valueForKey:@"Website"]];
    [_user_email addObject:[obj valueForKey:@"Email"]];
    [_user_subject addObject:[obj valueForKey:@"Subject"]];
```

### -------

```
 PHP Code:

<?

    $macaddress=$_GET['UserID'];

    include("dbConnection.php");

    $query="Select RegisterationID,Description,Website,Email,Subject from UserProfile INNER JOIN User
    ON        User.UserID = UserProfile.RegisterationID where User.UserID='$macaddress'";

     $result=mysql_query($query,$conn);     

        while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result)){  
        $photos[]=$row1;
        }


    $body = array();

    if (!empty($r))
        $body['r'] = $r;

    if (!empty($body))
        echo json_encode ($body);


        include("dbClose.php");     


 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to use Parse Cloud .

It's better and easier than mysql you don't need any php everything is automatic !

For more information : http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-app-backend-parse/

Comment: Thank you man I will consider that but any more answers please?